# How to define styles such as headings in Evernote

Tags: evernote

I'm migrating from Microsoft OneNote to Evernote and one of my biggest gripes is that Evernote does not have pre-defined styles. In particular, heading styles (h1, h2, h3) that I can access through a keyboard shortcut.

OneNote 2010 has that feature (although I can't modify them). I would pay for a special client just to have that feature in Evernote. Sure, I can change the formatting manually, but it gets very tedious to change the font, the size and the bold for every heading I'm creating.

Another style I use all the time is for code examples. Courier, 9px, no bold.
I'm sure this is not a requirement just for me.

Answer (score 2):

Well, the Evernote formatting tools have no such option, and there is no way you can do that.

Evernote and OneNote are a lot different, both made for different purposes.